# Magento showing random image on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images

I have created a product with multple images.

I have set the base image and even added a sort order but when I view my product, it shows a random image and not the main image. what is causing this?

Comment: Have you changed any code?

Comment: No. not changed any code

Answer (score 0):

Check this following class

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media
```

This class is used to manage product image sorting.
Make sure this class is not overwritten by any other module class.

Comment: I dont know how to check this?